# How to rewrite the exception message using my customize exception process class?

Tags: python, exception

How to catch the exception which have the same name in `MyException`'s method
and run the corresponding method defined in `MyException`? Because i want to
`rewrite the error message` with error code and error message.

```py
class OrmError:
    # catch django orm process error
    pass

class SysError:
    def IndexError(self):
        print("index error, you need to ...")

    def SomeError1(self):
        print('something1')

    def SomeError2(self):
        print('something2')

class OtherError:
    pass

class MyException(OrmError, SysError, OtherError):
    # do something
    pass


try:
    lis = []
    a = lis[1]
except MyException:
    # how to catch the exception which have the same name in MyException's method 
    # and run the corresponding method defined in MyException, because i want to 
    # rewrite the error message
    pass
except Exception as e:
    # print uncaught error
    print(e)
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use a class for this. A list or ordered dictionary would be better. Basically, you want to catch everything, and re-raise the same error after performing actions based on an `isinstance` or `type` lookup.

Comment: I will no help with the correct answer but in my opinion these should be 3 separate exception class (IndexError, SomeError1 and SomeError2). Each of these classes would implement __str__ method.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I want to rewrite many exception message(return my error code and error message) in my project, and use different class to maintain the error type, and some class many have over 10 types of error.

Comment: can't you just catch and re-raise each exception? e.g. try-`except IndexError; raise IndexError("my msg")`-- unless you have a very large number of different exceptions

Comment: In my project there are over 30 types of error code, i don't think use try-except is a good way to maintain different type of error, some may caused by django-orm, some for others.

Comment: You have generally the right idea, but I don't understand why you insist on using a class for this. It's just not the right container for a bunch of unrelated handlers that share no common state. Either way, I've posted an answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your reminding, I just saw your comment and answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def IndexError(self):
        print("index error, you need to ...")
    
    def SomeError1(self):
        print('something1')
    
    def SomeError2(self):
        print('something2')

try:
    lis = []
    a = lis[1]
except Exception as e:
    error_name = e.__class__.__name__

    if error_name in dir(MyException):
        # If error is handled in custom MyException
        ex = MyException()
        ex_function = getattr(ex, error_name)

        ex_function()
    else:
        # Otherwise, print default error message
        print(e)
```

`e.__class__.__name__` gives you the type of exception raised, which you can then use to check if it is being defined/handled in your custom class.

Comment: Thanks, my ideals are very similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Using classes in the way you are doing is an abuse of an otherwise effective tool. You are not trying to encapsulate anything here. Your idea of having a separate method for each exception you want to transform is fine, but you are missing a way to look up the exception type.

The simplest way to edit the message of a builtin exception is to modify the `args` attribute:

```
try:
    enumerate(1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)
    e.args = (e.args[0].replace('not ', ''),)
    raise
```

The result is

```
("'int' object is not iterable",)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-131-740297d24fb6>", line 1, in <module>
    try: enumerate(1)

TypeError: 'int' object is iterable
```

The next step is to provide a method of identifying exceptions and mapping their messages. You can do something similar to what a series of `except` blocks does: provide a list of the exceptions you want to catch, in the order you want to catch them, and supply a callable to transform each one. Order is important, so you can either use a list, or a an `OrderedDict`. In python 3.6+, regular dicts are ordered, but I will not rely on this functionality here.

You can transform the exceptions in a number of ways. The callables can accept an exception object or a string. They can return an exception object or a string, or nothing. I would recommend ingesting an returning nothing. This is because raising a specific exception object in an `except` clause, even if it is the same exception that triggered the clause, will restart the traceback. Compare the snippet above with the one below:

```
try:
    enumerate(1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)
    e.args = (e.args[0].replace('not ', ''),)
    raise e
```

Notice that the source of the error is no longer the `enumerate` line:

```
("'int' object is not iterable",)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-134-b1123bf70859>", line 6, in <module>
    raise e

  File "<ipython-input-134-b1123bf70859>", line 2, in <module>
    enumerate(1)

TypeError: 'int' object is iterable
```

So you can write something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def handleIndexError(e):
    e.args = ('You need to work on the size of your index',)

def handleMyCustomError(e):
    e.args = (f'Really, be more careful: some attribute {e.attr} needs to be better',)

def handleBadException(e):
    e.args = (f'This is a {type(e).__name__} error with message "{e.args[0]}"',)

handler_table = OrderedDict([
    (IndexError, handleIndexError),
    (MyCustomError, handleMyCustomError),
    ((MemoryError, OSError), handleBadException)])

def overwrite_exception(exception, table):
    for cls, handler in  table:
        if isinstance(exception, cls):
            return handler(exception)

try:
    lis = []
    a = lis[1]
except Exception as e:
    overwrite_exception(e, handler_table)
    raise
```

Notice that the `OrderedDict` does not give you much advantage over a `list` if you want to use `isinstance` functionality like the normal exceptions handlers do. If you want to match exact classes rather than using `isinstance`, you don't need ordering and a plain `dict` will do. In that case, you will have to list each type in a separate key. Normally, `isinstance` will accept a tuple, as in the last key of `handler_table` shown above.

The reason for having your handler accept the full exception object is that not all exceptions will use `args` for their `str` representation (or even have an `args` attribute. If you come across a type that uses a different mechanism to create the string representation, having the full exception object will allow you to adapt to it.

Also, don't forget about [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info), which can be used to glean information about the exception not available directly in the object itself.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I use a class with different method to manage the similar type error, if i use your solution, it's hard to do this, and i need to maintain the mapping, in addition i need to import many exception type as the first item in the tuple of the OrderedDict. This is my current thinking:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63848174/how-to-rewrite-the-exception-message-using-my-customize-exception-process-class/63848574#63848574

Comment: A class is just a namespace. I don't know why it's harder for you to do this rather than abuse a class. All the methods you've shown can be `@staticmethod`, which means that you don't need a class to begin with...

Answer (score 0):

I can achieve my goal in the following way, but i think this is not elegant. Is there a better way?

```py
class OrmHandlelException(object):
    def IntegrityError(self):
        print('Integrity error')
        
# there may be many other type of exception 
# which i also want to classify with independent class        
class OtherException(object):
    pass      


class MyExceptionHandler(OrmHandlelException, OtherException):
    def __call__(self, error):
        error_handle_method = getattr(self, type(error).__name__, None)
        if error_handle_method is not None:
            error_handle_method()
        else:
            print(error)
    
my_exception_handler = MyExceptionHandler()    

try:
    print('do something here')
    lis = []
    a = lis[1]
except Exception as error:
    my_exception_handler(error)
```

Comment: You at least need `my_exception_handler()(error)` Otherwise you are just initializing an instance of `MyExceptionHandler` with `error`, which does nothing. Might even throw another error...

Comment: `my_exception_handler` is the instance of `MyExceptionHandler` , when i call `my_exception_handler(error)` it will call `__call__(self, error)`, i don't need to initiate it again.

Comment: Right. I misread. But again, why do you create an entire class with a `__call__` method just to use a single instance as a function? Why not just use a function?

Comment: Because this can manage different errors of the `similar type` through inherited classes.

Comment: It's much more elegant, and flexible, to use a method. You're really abusing the system